# Read/Write on Raspberry Pi 3 Bluez C/C++

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluez

Once I'm connected to a bluetooth device I try to read and write a request by handle or uuid (I tried both) with no success.

I'm using this library https://github.com/labapart/gattlib which works for the examples of ble_scan and discover with little changes.

The problem is that the example read_write:
https://github.com/labapart/gattlib/blob/master/examples/read_write/read_write.c

Never fills the buffer used in both functions  `gattlib_read_char_by_uuid(connection, &g_uuid, buffer, sizeof(buffer));`
and `gattlib_write_char_by_handle(connection, handle, buffer, sizeof(buffer));`

Any idea of were could the problem be?
If not, can anyone tell me where could I find read/write examples with Bluez for Linux in C/C++?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wonder did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: No, sorry @JohnSmith

Answer (score 0):

When you said it does not fill, did `gattlib` was returning an error?

Did you manage to connect to the BLE device? Have you tried to access your BLE device with `gatttool`?

Possible issues are:
- your BLE device requires to be connected with a RANDOM address (and not PUBLIC).
- You need to increase the security level when connecting to the device

On a side note, I have just added DBus support to [gattlib](https://github.com/labapart/gattlib/).

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Can you tell me how to connect with increasing security ? Also What should be the handle given if I want to read battery service like in the question ? I dont want to do it as DBus though.